# Git Credential Manager for Windows and credentials in a file

Tags: git, jenkins, git-credential-winstore

How can I get the [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) (GCM) to read credentials from a file for HTTPS Git URLs? We need this in order to facilitate automatic cloning operations for Jenkins jobs.

**Background**

We have been successfully using the `store` credential store in Git 1.7 on Windows prior to upgrading to [Git for Windows v2.9.0](https://git-for-windows.github.io/). Now the CGM always asks for credentials causing the Jenkins build to hang.

I notice the GCM [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows#build-agents) mention a `credential.interactive never` setting but how can I tell it which file to read the credentials from? And what format is it expecting in that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [asking on the GCM Github issues page](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/230) it turns out that the GCM does not support reading credentials from a file.

But my goal is to allow non-interactive population of credentials and it does support programmatically adding credentials to the Windows Credential Store that GCM uses under the hood. By using the [bundled libraries](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/tree/master/Microsoft.Alm.Authentication) ([binaries here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.4.0)) I was able to put together a Powershell script that allowed us to add credentials during machine provisioning by Chef :

```
Add-Type -Path 'c:\path\to\gcm-v1.4.0\Microsoft.Alm.Authentication.dll'

$credentials = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Alm.Authentication.Credential('someuser', 'secret')
$targetUri = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Alm.Authentication.TargetUri('https://git.example.com/projects')
$namespace = "git"
$secretStore = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Alm.Authentication.SecretStore($namespace, $null, $null, $null)

$foundCredentials = $null
$secretStore.ReadCredentials($targetUri, [ref] $foundCredentials)
if ($foundCredentials -ne $null) {
    echo "Credentials already found, not inserting"
} else {
    echo "Inserting stored credentials"
    $secretStore.WriteCredentials($targetUri, $credentials)
}
```

This allows the Jenkins slave to perform Git clones without user interaction.

**Note:** You will need to run the Powershell script with the "Unrestricted" execution policy as well as [unblock](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849924.aspx) the DLLs included in the GCM otherwise they won't load.